# unable to pass AWS credentials to node docker container

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, dockerfile

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:9.2

WORKDIR /migration-ui

COPY migration-ui/package.json /migration-ui

RUN npm install

COPY migration-ui /migration-ui

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

when I run it, it fails with this error
`unable to download: CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1`
I've tried passing the credentials as environments and as arguments but it still fails `const awsContainerCredentialsRelativeUri = !!process.env.AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`
the value of variable awsContainerCredentialsRelativeUri is always false.

Comment: You can find all the ways to use AWS credentials here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-quickstart.html. I think you could create a `credentials` file and copy it to the `.aws` directory in the container.

Comment: In which AWS service?